# OnClick : return false is not working

Tags: javascript

Before deleting data, I want a confirmation message " ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE IT?". So I did this:

**HTML**

```
 <a href="delete.php?id=2" onclick="return warning();">DELETE NOW</a>
```

**js**

```
<script>
   function warning()
     {
        if(confirm('ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE IT?'))
          {
             return true;
          }
        else
          {
             return false;
          }
     }
</script>
```

**Problem**
When I click the link, a confirmation message will appear. If I click OK then it will proceed to delete.php. On the other hand, If I click CANCEL it also proceed to delete.php. How can I prevent the page from proceeding to delete.php if I click CANCEL?

Comment: what have the method confirm();???

Comment: @WearFox it's a built in browser method.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, [it works fine here](http://jsbin.com/barunisedubo/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: cant replicate your issue

Comment: are you sure that add onclick handler once?

Comment: is because the method href="delete.php?id=2"  is actived don't have any conection with the event onclick that you have

Comment: that should work .. may be you can try event.preventDefault() on top of warning function to stop default action

Answer (score 1):

use

```
return confirm('ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE IT?');
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you should just return the confirm result if you want to do it that way

```
function warning() {
  return confirm('....');
}
```

2) I'd have delete now in a

```
<button onClick='warning();'>Delete Now</button>
```

then in the warning function, do an AJAX call to `delete.php?id=2`

3) if you're going to have a few of these delete buttons, I'd probably make it dynamic, pass in the id to the warning function and have the js append it to the query string

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show your full listing?

In general:
It is not the best idea to use javascript in "onclick" attribute. You may try to use addEventListener instead.